# css debugging, cross-browser compatibility

Tags: css, layout, html, cross-browser

There are two `<div></div>` tags. When it is browsed using Firefox, the effect is desirable. There is a gap between `.steven` and `.john`. However when it is browsed using IE, the effect is undesirable; `.Steven` and `.john` are connected together(There is no gap). How to solve this problem?

```
.steven{
     position: relative;
     width: 620px;
     left: 55px;
     float: left;

     }

    .john {
     position: relative;
     width: 270px;
     right: 35px;
     float: right;


    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask here, what do you mean by connected?

Comment: There is no gap between two <div></div> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used a [Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/)?

Different browsers have different defaults for display on different elements.